# How to resolve "The type or namespace name 'Didstopia' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Tags: compiler-errors, nuget, nuget-package, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard-2.0

I'm using VS2019 trying to build a simple .NET Standard 2.0 class library that uses the Didstopia.PDFSharp .NET Standard 2.0 nuget package.

Here's a minimal reproduction starting with my .csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netstandard2.0</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Didstopia.PDFSharp" Version="1.0.0-beta8">
      <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
      <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers; buildtransitive</IncludeAssets>
    </PackageReference>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

And here's my Class1.cs file:

```
using System;
using Didstopia.PDFSharp;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
    }
}
```

When I compile I get the following message:

```
Class1.cs(2,7,2,16): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Didstopia' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

In Visual Studio in the code editing window for Class1 the "using Didstopia.PDFSharp" line has Didstopia underlined in red.

If instead of using a package reference I use a assembly reference to the Didstopia.PDFSharp.dll, from the packages folder, the class library compiles fine.

If I fork, clone and add a Project Reference to Didstopia.PDFSharp.dll everything compiles fine.

I've done "clean", delete bin & obj folders, removed the Didstopia package from the C:\Users\[myuserid]\.nuget\packages\didstopia.pdfsharp folder innumerable times.

I'm not sure what to even try next. Is there anyway to get more information out of the compiler about **why** it doesn't like the package reference?

Comment: Please remove the content of `IncludeAssets` and then try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I'm not sure what to even try next. Is there anyway to get more
>   information out of the compiler about why it doesn't like the package
>   reference?

I think it is an issue of the nuget package `Didstopia.PDFSharp 1.0.0-beta8`. In my side, when l install this package in a net standard 2.0 class library project, I faced the same issue as you described and feel quite strange about it.

**As a suggestion**, please delete the content of `<IncludeAssets>` just like this:

`<IncludeAssets></IncludeAssets>`

This tag is about to consume the content of the nuget package and when you use it, you cannot reference the content of the dll. Pleae see [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files#controlling-dependency-assets).

**Besides,** since this issue is more related to the package itself and it is a beta, prerelease version which may have some problems, I suggest you could contact with [the author](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Didstopia.PDFSharp/) and report this issue.

Hope it could help you.

Comment: Thanks that worked! I wish there was better diagnostic information to assist with tracking down what's wrong. It's a bit weird because based on what I can see the package only contains a single .DLL and nothing else. I'll reach out to the package developer and let them know.